# In press Spacebar's Search Menu, can i use ctrl+n and ctrl+p choose ward?

Tags: python

I want use ctrl+n and ctrl+p, for choose candidate in search menu.
yeah I mean like Vim behavior!
anyone know that?
Of course we can use python script.